# How to apply viewing angle with three.js?

Tags: three.js, shader, perspectivecamera, post-processing

In the scene, there is an object that I'm looking at with a `PerspectiveCamera`. Using `OrbitControls`, I can move around the object.

I want to set viewing angle to the camera.

Concretely, here is the [example](https://www.posemaniacs.com/viewer/0000301%2300002) where the behavior I suppose is realized.
Click camera icon and you find the slider to change viewing angle.

Is it possible to realize this, using `PerspectiveCamera`?
Or should I use Effect Composer for Post Processing? If so, I look for shader code.

[image]

Comment: you might try to change the position of the camera `camera.position.set(0.1, 30, 15);` and the rotation `camera.rotation.set(0.0, 0.0, Math.PI/2);`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This way doesn't seem to express the distortion of depth like the example, though I tried.